# Fastest way to subset sub-elements of lists in R

Tags: r, list, filter, tidyverse

Say I have a list of lists where each sub-list is a move:

```
movies <- list(list("Jurassic Park", "Steven Spielberg", "Action"),
               list("Avatar", "James Cameron", "Action"),
               list("Schindler's List", "Steven Spielberg", "Biography")
           )
```

What is the best/fastest way (preferably without dependencies, but tidyverse would be fine) to subset that list based on the sub-list elements? That is, if director is always the second element in the sub-list, what's the fastest way to get a vector of the names of movies that Spielberg directed?

Hoping to do this across very large lists many times.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency free and readable:

```
sapply(movies, getElement, 2)
# [1] "Steven Spielberg" "James Cameron"    "Steven Spielberg"
```

Fast but not readable and assumes each sublist is length 3:

```
unlist(movies)[-1L:(length(movies) * 3L-2L) %% 3L == 0L]
```

Playing with Rcpp (perhaps not optimal)

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  Rcpp::CharacterVector foo(Rcpp::List lst, int idx, int n) {
      idx--;
      Rcpp::CharacterVector res(n);
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Rcpp::List tmp = lst(i);
        res(i) = Rcpp::as<String>(tmp(idx));
      }
      return res;
  }  
')
```

Benchmark with 100k sublists:

```
bench::mark(purrr = map_chr(movies, pluck, 2), 
            getElement = sapply(movies, getElement, 2),
            `[[` = sapply(movies, `[[`, 2),
            unlist = unlist(movies)[-1L:(length(movies) * 3L-2L) %% 3L == 0L],
            Rcpp = foo(movies, 2L, length(movies))
  )

#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result          memory              time            gc      
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>          <list>              <list>          <list>  
# 1 purrr       234.6ms 236.78ms      4.15   781.3KB     13.8     3    10      723ms <chr [100,000]> <Rprofmem [42 × 3]> <bench_tm [3]>  <tibble>
# 2 getElement  73.06ms  77.53ms     12.8     3.29MB     14.6     7     8      548ms <chr [100,000]> <Rprofmem [5 × 3]>  <bench_tm [7]>  <tibble>
# 3 [[          28.09ms  30.43ms     27.1     3.29MB     10.2    16     6      590ms <chr [100,000]> <Rprofmem [5 × 3]>  <bench_tm [16]> <tibble>
# 4 unlist       7.81ms   8.16ms    105.      8.01MB     17.8    53     9      506ms <chr [100,000]> <Rprofmem [7 × 3]>  <bench_tm [53]> <tibble>
# 5 Rcpp        11.91ms  12.86ms     70.8   783.79KB     15.7    36     8      508ms <chr [100,000]> <Rprofmem [2 × 3]>  <bench_tm [36]> <tibble>
```

A small function out of the comment below movies that includes filtering:

```
return_movies <- function(list, title_position, comparison_position, comparison_string) {
  sapply(movies, getElement, title_position)[
        sapply(movies, getElement, comparison_position) == comparison_string
         ]
}

return_movies(movies, 1, 2, "Steven Spielberg")

[1] "Jurassic Park"    "Schindler's List"
```

Answer (score 4):

```r
sapply(movies, `[[`, 2)
# [1] "Steven Spielberg" "James Cameron"    "Steven Spielberg"
```

Benchmark: this answer is the fastest.

```r
bench::mark(purrr = map_chr(movies, pluck, 2), 
            getElement = sapply(movies, getElement, 2),
            `[[` = sapply(movies, `[[`, 2))

  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc
1 purrr        21.7µs  28.2µs  31773.      0B    6.36  9998     2
2 getElement   16.6µs  18.6µs  45652.      0B    4.57  9999     1
3 [[           14.9µs  17.2µs  47417.      0B    4.74  9999     1
```

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly the comparison I was hoping for!! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(purrr)

map_chr(movies, pluck, 2)
#> [1] "Steven Spielberg" "James Cameron"    "Steven Spielberg"
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized base R approach that doesn't assume vector lengths inside the list:

```
bigmovies <- rep(movies, 1e4)

fsub1 <- function(x, i) unlist(x)[c(i, cumsum(lengths(x)[-length(x)]) + i)]
fsub2 <- function(x, i) sapply(x, `[[`, i)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(unlist = fsub1(bigmovies, 2),
                               sapply = fsub2(bigmovies, 2),
                               check = "identical")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>  unlist 1.8197 1.86370 2.113037 1.90760 2.15050 11.7461   100
#>  sapply 7.5128 7.68515 8.309795 7.90885 9.01275 13.5639   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following base R option

```
> (d <- do.call(cbind, movies))[1, colSums(d == "Steven Spielberg") > 0]
[[1]]
[1] "Jurassic Park"

[[2]]
[1] "Schindler's List"
```